# How to unmark just one date in the calendar -- delete overlay

Tags: emacs, elisp

Error message:  `let: Wrong type argument: overlayp, (#<overlay from 478 to 480 in *Calendar*>)`

`mouse-1` successfully marks a date in the calendar.  The built-in functions only provide for deleting all of the overlays, instead of just one particular date.  Could anyone please give me a hand to delete the overlay for just one marked date -- I was thinking this could be either `mouse-2` or `U`.  I thought of using skip-syntax-forwards/backwards because some of the dates have just one digit, and some have two digits -- the cursor may be between two digits or on either side of the date.  I assume we need a beginning and ending point.

```
(define-key calendar-mode-map [mouse-1] (lambda () (interactive)
  (calendar-mark-visible-date (calendar-cursor-to-date t))))

(define-key calendar-mode-map "U" (lambda () (interactive)
  (cond
    ((save-excursion (> 0 (skip-syntax-backward "w")))
      (skip-syntax-backward "w")
      (let ((beg (point)))
        (skip-syntax-forward "w")
          (let ((end (point)))
            (delete-overlay (overlays-in beg end)))))
    ((save-excursion (< 0 (skip-syntax-forward "w")))
      (skip-syntax-forward "w")
      (let ((end (point)))
        (skip-syntax-backward "w")
          (let ((beg (point)))
            (delete-overlay (overlays-in beg end))))))))
```

---

**EDIT** (December 12, 2013):   First working draft based upon the helpful answer from @Drew.  Added `mouse-set-point` and interactive code to support said function.  Consolidated keyboard shortcuts so that `mouse-1` activates / deactivates the overlay at point -- now uses `overlays-at`.

**EDIT** (January 1, 2014):  To distinguish between one or more overlays at point, see the following thread:  [How to distinguish between different overlays at point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715445/how-to-distinguish-between-different-overlays-at-point)  With the examples in that thread, different actions can occur depending upon whether a particular overlay exists at point.

```
(defvar lawlist-calendar-face (make-face 'lawlist-calendar-face))
(set-face-attribute 'lawlist-calendar-face nil
  :background "LightCoral" :foreground "black")

(define-key calendar-mode-map [mouse-1] (lambda (event) (interactive "e")
  (mouse-set-point event)
  (if (not (overlays-at (point)))
    (calendar-mark-visible-date (calendar-cursor-to-date t) lawlist-calendar-face)
  (cond
    ;; cursor is one whitespace to the left of 1 to 9
    ((and
        (save-excursion (< 0 (skip-chars-forward " \t")))
        (not (save-excursion (< 0 (skip-syntax-forward "w")))))
      (save-excursion
        (let ((beg (point)))
          (skip-chars-forward " \t")
          (skip-syntax-forward "w")
            (let ((end (point)))
              (mapc 'delete-overlay (overlays-in beg end))))))
    ;; cursor is sandwiched between a digit on each side.
    ((and
        (save-excursion (> 0 (skip-syntax-backward "w")))
        (save-excursion (< 0 (skip-syntax-forward "w"))))
      (save-excursion
        (skip-syntax-backward "w")
        (let ((beg (point)))
          (skip-syntax-forward "w")
            (let ((end (point)))
              (mapc 'delete-overlay (overlays-in beg end))))))
    ;; cursor is to the far right of one or two digit dates
    ((and
        (save-excursion (> 0 (skip-syntax-backward "w")))
        (not (save-excursion (< 0 (skip-syntax-forward "w")))))
      (save-excursion
        (skip-syntax-backward "w")
        (let ((beg (point)))
          (skip-syntax-forward "w")
            (let ((end (point)))
              (mapc 'delete-overlay (overlays-in beg end))))))
    ;; cursor to the far left of one or two digits dates
    ((and
        (save-excursion (< 0 (skip-syntax-forward "w")))
        (not (save-excursion (> 0 (skip-syntax-backward "w")))))
      (save-excursion
        (skip-syntax-forward "w")
        (let ((end (point)))
          (skip-syntax-backward "w")
            (let ((beg (point)))
              (mapc 'delete-overlay (overlays-in beg end))))))))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrt the error:

`delete-overlay` expects a single overlay as its argument.  You are passing it a list (empty or nonempty) of overlays instead.  You should iterate over the list, e.g., with `while` or `dolist` or `mapc`.