# How to distinguish between different overlays at point

Tags: emacs, elisp

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**:  I'm looking for some assistance, please, to distinguish between overlays that may exist at point.  If the `overlays-at` point is made with the `lawlist-red-face` then do `X`.  If the `overlays-at` point is made with `calendar-holiday-marker`, then do `Y`.  The overlays are made with these two functions.

```
(calendar-mark-visible-date (car holiday) lawlist-red-face)

(calendar-mark-visible-date (car holiday) calendar-holiday-marker)
```

---

**EDIT** (January 1, 2014):  @Drew wrote a nice test for this in `calendar+.el` ( http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/calendar%2B.el ):

```
(when
  (memq lawlist-red-face
    (mapcar (function (lambda (ovr)
      (overlay-get ovr 'face)))  (overlays-at (point))))
  ... )
```

---

**EDIT** (February 13, 2014):  The above-listed snippet can also be used in conjunction with something like `(while (re-search-backward "[0-9]" nil t)` to create a combined list of dates with overlays -- month, day and year are extracted with `calendar-extract-day`, `calendar-extract-month` and `calendar-extract-year` -- the date is obtained with `(calendar-cursor-to-nearest-date)`:

```
;; modified with the help of @phils based on comments down below.
(setq lawlist-mouse-marked
  (append lawlist-mouse-marked
    `((holiday-sexp '(list ,month ,day ,year) ""))))
```

That list can then be used with something like `calendar-holiday-list` (or the modified code below) to remark dates on a new calendar layout after it has been generated.  This is useful if the user has manually marked dates (e.g., with the mouse) and wants those dates to reappear after scrolling the calendar forwards / backwards.  The library `holidays.el` contains the function `holiday-sexp` which uses a filtering function `holiday-filter-visible-calendar` to edit the list of dates so that only those that are visible on the new calendar get marked:

```
(dolist (holiday
  (let (res h err)
    (sort
      (dolist (p lawlist-mouse-marked res)
        (if (setq h (eval p))
           (setq res (append h res))))
      'calendar-date-compare)))
  (calendar-mark-visible-date (car holiday) lawlist-mouse-calendar-face))
```

Comment: You realise that the cumbersome-looking form you're passing to `read` could alternatively be one single `format` string with multiple arguments, yeah?

Comment: @phils -- I tried copying an example from the variable `calendar-holidays` documentation (in `holidays.el`):  `(holiday-sexp '(if (zerop (% year 4)) (calendar-gregorian-from-absolute (1+ (calendar-dayname-on-or-before 1 (+ 6 (calendar-absolute-from-gregorian (list 11 1 year))))))) \"US Presidential Election\")`  Without using `read`, I get -- e.g., Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument listp "((holiday-sexp '(list 7 30 2014) \"US Presidential Election\\.\"))") append((40 40 108 9. . . .  I use the `holiday-sexp` to place overlays on the calendar for appointments and birthdays.

Comment: No, I meant that your *argument* to `read` could be a single `(format "..." month day year)`

Comment: That said, I hadn't even looked at the purpose of the `read`, and I'm really not sure why you're doing that either. Perhaps something like `\`((holiday-sexp '(list ,month ,day ,year) ""))` would suffice there??

Comment: Both of your suggestions worked perfectly -- thank you!!! I'll revise the code in this question to match your suggestions, and I'll fix them in my own source files also.  Greatly appreciated!  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, let's try to figure this out (without really knowing anything about the calendar).

`(overlays-at)` returns a list of overlays. I will keep this simple and only handle the first, if you want to examine all of them, simply loop over them until you find one that is suitable.

Also, the `face` property can be more complex than simply the name of the face, if that is the case you would need to handle that as well.

But anyway, here is a simple piece of code that (hopefully) does what you want:

```
(let ((overlays (overlays-at (point))))
  (if overlays
      (let ((face (overlay-get (car overlays) 'face)))
        (cond ((eq face 'lawlist-red-face)
               ;; Do something
               )
              ((eq face 'holiday)
               ;; Do another thing
               )
              (t
               ;; Do something else)))))
```

Comment: Since the `calendar-holiday-marker` uses the `holiday` face, I just substituted it for the latter in the code.

Comment: You must look at **all** overlays, and not just the first one.  There may be other, unrelated overlays at point, and according to the documentation, the return value of `overlays-at` has no particular order.

Comment: @lunaryorn -- To quote myself: "(overlays-at) returns a list of overlays. I will keep this simple and only handle the first, if you want to examine all of them, simply loop over them until you find one that is suitable."